# Transferring info from MS Access db to MySQL db

Tags: c#, mysql, logic

I am making a program to audit some of our workers. I need some help figuring out how to do this next process.

I have a MS Access database that I am pulling information from. This information is being stored in a dictionary of `<string, UserClass>.` The string is the user's name and the UserClass contains a list of "ControlNumbers" that are assigned to that particular user. So user "jsmith" would have controlNumber = "123456" assigned to him.

I then want to use this controlNumber to fill in a blank database specifically made for audits. So in this new Audit Database, I have a table called 'Events'. This table contains many columns, but has a column named "controlNumbers"...so what I want to do is >> update this Audit Databse with all the information from the MS Access database based on the controlNumber that I have.

I am just curious about the logic of doing this right now. Should this be one function or multiple? and if multiple, what function does each sub have?

I was thinking about saving all the information for each table from the Access database into a dataadapter and then trying to route the dataadapter to the MySQL database. Is this possible?

Hint: all of the tables, columns, and fields are named the same in both databases.

Comment: "This information is being stored in a dictionary of " ???? What?

Comment: '<string, USER>' .. USER is a class that stores the Name of the user and a List of ControlNumbers assigned to each user

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, you have a database in MS ACCESS and you want to import the data from that to MySQL?

If so, you can try to export from access to any ODBC database using the Export functionality in MS ACCESS.

If that somehow isn't working for you, try [Access To MySQL](http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php).

Comment: You are correct. That is what I essentially want to do. However, this isn't just a one time thing. This will be part of a program that runs daily. The MS db is our production database being used by 80 or so employees and the MySQL db will be used just for Auditing their work...so every time the program runs, I want to move the corresponding information from the MS to MySQL db. Is that possible?